# ValueError when trying to create float from (50, 20.0, 3.1599)

Tags: python

So I am stuck, I know the error is a ValueError unable to convert string to float. I just don't understand why. This is the lab I am working on:

> Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal
> point, which can be achieved as follows:
> print('{:.2f}'.format(your_value))
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> ```
> 20.0                                
> 3.1599
> ```
>
> the output is:
>
> ```
> 1.58  
> 7.90  
> 63.20
> ```
>
> Your program must define and call the following `driving_cost()`
> function. Given input parameters driven_miles, `miles_per_gallon`, and
> `dollars_per_gallon`, the function returns the dollar cost to drive
> those miles.    Ex: If the function is called with:    `50  20.0  3.1599` the function returns: `7.89975`   `def driving_cost(driven_miles, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon)`
>
> Your program should call the function three times to determine the gas
> cost for 10 miles, 50 miles, and 400 miles.

Here is my code:

```
def driving_cost(driven_miles, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
    cost = (driven_miles/miles_per_gallon)*dollars_per_gallon
    return cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    driven_miles = int(input())
    miles_per_gallon = float(input())
    dollars_per_gallon = float(input())
    for i in range(len(driven_miles)):
        cost = driving_cost(driven_miles[i], miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon)
    print('{:.2f}'.format(cost))
```

As I stated above, I am extremely new to this, just trying to understand why I am getting a `ValueError: could not convert string to float`: when entering the input like this `(50, 20.0, 3.1599)`. But if I enter the other value with the breaks in it like:

```
20.0   
3.1599
```

it goes through for me. I am definitely missing something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. In particular, question titles should be a concise summary of the question, not a statement about your experience level. And please include the _full_ error message, with traceback, in your question. That should provide more information about what is going wrong.

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to enter `(50, 20.0, 3.1599)` as your input? I don't see anything here that tries to take input like that and split it into individual values. And why are you even trying to do that? The question formatting is a bit confusing, but it looks to me like you're being asked to accept the inputs one at a time.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem with a simple bit of code that anyone can copy and paste to test it you'll usually get a very fast answer. It appears that you've excluded some information necessary to answer your question, which makes the simplified example all the more important. My guess is that you are passing in a `string`, not a `float`. If you add print statements such as `print(type(driving_miles))` or `print(type(cost))` what do you see?

Comment: Why do you have the line "for i in range(len(driven_miles)):"?

Answer (score 0):

[`input()` reads one line from standard input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).  Your code takes that line and tries to convert it to an `int` or `float`.  But python can't interpret `(50, 20.0, 3.1599)` as an int or float.

You can write your program to parse `(50, 20.0, 3.1599)` as an input string.  Or you can write your program to read 3 lines of input an parse each as one of those values.  Or you could write your program to support both.  But you can't write your program to read 3 lines of input and then expect it to successfully parse alternative formats of input data.

If you are trying to input all 3 of those inputs to the program in the format the program currently expects, separate each line with the line terminator.  In a Posix flavored shell that could look something like:

```
python myprogram.py <<<"1
2
3
"
```

It's a much better technique than individually typing in every input as you test your program!

As an aside, in the real world, `input()` is very rarely used.  In fact interactive program input is very rare in everywhere except computer programming coursework.  In the real world user input is more often provided as [command line arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).  If standard input *is* the source of data it's often formatted with a spec like Json or Yaml (etc) that doesn't leave ambiguity in how the data should be formatted.

Even if your coursework requires you to collect ostensibly interactive user input, try to remove it from SO questions whenever possible.  Instead *hard code* the input data into the code you post to make your code more reproducible.  `input()` is a common tripping point so if you can take it out of the equation, do so.  I suspect if you would have tried to do that here, you would have quickly realized that no single variable in your program was a proper place to store the input `(50, 20.0, 3.1599)`.

Good luck with your studies!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to use a loop, it sounds like you want to use a List:

```
def driving_cost(distance, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon):
    print('{:.2f}'.format(distance/miles_per_gallon*dollars_per_gallon))

MPG = float(input('Enter miles per gallon (eg 20.0): '))
DPG = float(input('Enter dollars per gallon (eg 3.1599): '))

driven_miles_list = [10, 50, 400]
for distance in driven_miles_list:
     driving_cost(distance, MPG, DPG)
```